# Talend XML metadata with multiple similar tags within the loop

Tags: xml, talend

I was wondering what would be the best way to create metadata of an XML file with this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<django-objects version="1.0">
    <object pk="8" model="auth.user">
        <field type="CharField" name="username">jd</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="first_name">John</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="last_name">Doe</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="email">bla@bla.com</field>
    </object>
    <object pk="2102684" model="auth.user">
        <field type="CharField" name="username">kr</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="first_name">Karl</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="last_name">Row</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="email">karl@test.com</field>
    </object>
  .... etc
</django-objects>
```

The problem here is that the  tag repeats multiple times (instead of having a separate `<username>, <first_name>`, etc tag), which causes the default metadata mapping to only return the first occurance (username).

How can I best map this kind of data?

Thanks
koen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was a newbee question I guess: I figured it out. I just need to use XPATH to map the fields to new columns. For instance:

```
    <field type="CharField" name="username">jd</field>
```

maps like this using a tFileInputMSXML component:

```
    "field[@name='username']".
```

Every `field` tag is mapped like this. Works like a charm.